# Is it secure to use pbkdf2 for both password hashing and key generation

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm writing a password manager, right now for each individual site, I already used master password + random salt with PBKDF2 to generate encryption key to encrypt its password (each site has its own salt).

Is it still secure to use master password + another random salt with PBKDF2 to generate hash for master password (this hash will be store in DB for user authentication)? Or should I use a hashing algorithm like SHA-256?

Comment: What's the point of not using the master password+slat directly for encrypting a given password ? I don't see how your system improves security.

Comment: @Stephane because master password+salt will be store in db to authenticate user, and I certainly don't want to store the encryption key in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PBKDF2 could be use to generate as much bytes as you want/need, you can of course use it for both master password hashing and key generation. You don't even need to use different salt, just generate a n bytes hash, then generate n+m bytes, discard the first n bytes and use the other m bytes as key.